# How to convert an entire list of strings to a normal array or list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable which is `a = '"[200.0', ' 100.0]"'`. While trying to access individual element like `a[0] = '"[200.0'`
The data type of this I checked says tuple. This is not the format I can work on, hence I want to convert this to a simple list/array like the following format for ex:
`a = [200.0,100.0]` .So that `a[0] = 200.0` which could be either float or int data type.

I have tried using `literal_eval`, `eval` but it keeps throwing an error. A workable solution would be really helpful. Any ideas for this?

Comment: Where does this data come from? The format you're showing here really makes no sense. Fixing the source seems like a better idea than trying to cope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with regex to clean the `a` string from unwanted characters and then split it by the `,` to be a list

```
import re

a = '"[200.0', ' 100.0]"'
a = [re.sub(r"""["'\[\] ]""", "",i) for i in a]
print(a)
```

Output

```
['200.0', '100.0']
```

OR 
if you want it to be from float type

```
a = [float(re.sub(r"""["'\[\] ]""", "",i)) for i in a]
print(a)
```

Output

```
[200.0, 100.0]
```

Comment: - I tried both the mthods you mentioned, but obtained the following error  ```----> 4 [float(i) for i in re.sub(r"""["'\[\] ]""", "", ex).split(",")]        TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object```

Comment: I've updated the code now it should work for you.

Comment: It's strange - run the first code and got this: `>>> a =
['', '2', '0', '0', '.', '0', '', ',', '', '', '', '1', '0', '0', '.', '0', ''] `?

Comment: @DanielHao you can try now this is with the original `a` from the question

Comment: Thanks.  @LeoArad, `re` is powerful, given it's by itself a `mini language` . Wonder if there is non-re approach... ;-)

Comment: There is a way with `replace()` method of string.

Comment: @DanielHao -- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65793523/how-to-convert-an-entire-list-of-strings-to-a-normal-array-or-list/65794391#65794391) is a non `re` approach.

Comment: Yeah. ~@fountainhead - but `eval` is dangerous?!~  right?

Comment: @DanielHao -- Perhaps it wouldn't be polite of me to discuss that under this answer's comments section :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you could also try this:

```
my_list = eval(eval(",".join(a)))
```

**Explanation:**

1. `",".join(a)` produces a single string `'"[200.0, 100.0]"'`
2. Calling `eval()` on this strips away the outer single-quotes, producing `"[200.0, 100.0]"` (that's a string containing `[` as the first character and `]` as the last)
3. Calling `eval()` again on this evaluates the above string, producing `[200.0, 100.0]`, which gets assigned to `my_list` as a proper `list` object